# How to take the data from an R time-series plot?

Tags: r

```
library(data.table)

var = fread("Q:\\Electricity\\Analysis\\6 Working\\NZ Power\\Jack Perry\\Rainfall\\Clutha R (V01).csv")

var.ts = ts(var$Rainfall, start = c(2008,5),end = c(2020), frequency = 53)
n = length(var.ts)
n
print(var.ts)
plot(var.ts);
var.decomp = stl(var.ts,s.window = 'periodic', t.window = 500)
plot(var.decomp)
```

Hi,
I need help pulling the data from a timeseries decomposition. I want to take the data from the seasonal component (not just look at the plot).

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Please add data using `dput`. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is a `list` of elements.  So, we extract the 'time.series' component and get the 'seasonal' column

```
var.decomp$time.series[, "seasonal"]
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I pull one year from this data? So I pull 365 points?

Comment: @JackPerry I think there is an index with the date component in that.  So, you could use standard extraction methods for extraction.  Can you show a small dput so that I can test it